# SVG / Animation : Trying to animate an SVG (with feTurbulence/feDisplacementMap), got cross-browser issues

Tags: css, animation, svg, cross-browser

Really need some help here. I need to create a fading radial gradient with a noisy touch that fill the viewport and can be animate.

The SVG filter seemed to be the best solution at first (light, smooth, etc.) but I hit major cross-browser issues.

Am I missing something?

Note: I am open to other stack (WebGL, shaders, etc.) but that's beyond my knowledge.

Cross-browser issues:

- Chrome: everything's perfect
- Firefox: offset
- Safari: don't work at all

Link to my pen: https://codepen.io/jesuismaxime/pen/bGgZKEL

```css
:root {
  --top: #C4E9FB;
  --duration: 4s;
  --state: running; // paused | running
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.-background {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: var(--top);
}
 
.-background svg {
position: absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 2;
}

.-background svg  .-shape {
  animation: pulse infinite alternate ease-in-out var(--duration);
  -webkit-animation: pulse infinite alternate ease-in-out var(--duration);
  animation-play-state: var(--state);
  -webkit-animation-play-state: var(--state);
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
r: 0; 
  }
  50% {
r: 150vw; 
  }
  100% {
r: 150vw; 
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
r: 0; 
  }
  50% {
r: 150vw; 
  }
  100% {
r: 150vw; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="-background">
  <svg
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
  >
<filter 
  id="noise" 
  x="0" 
  y="0" 
  width="100vw" 
  height="100vh"
  filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
  _primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
>
  <feTurbulence
    type='turbulence'
    baseFrequency='2.5'
    numOctaves="2"               
    result="NOISE"      
    seed="10"
  />
  <feDisplacementMap
    in2="NOISE"
    in="SourceGraphic"
    scale="400" 
    xChannelSelector="B"
    yChannelSelector="R"        
  />
</filter>
<circle
  class="-shape"
  fill="#FFF"
  filter="url(#noise)" 
  cx="40vw"
  cy="40vh" 
  r="10vw"
/>
  </svg>
</div>
```